# speed up numpy array averaging by block

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numpy-ndarray

Is it possible to speed up the following code? Here `xyz` is the Nx3 coordinate array of all the atoms in many identical molecules. `mol_atom_indices` can be thought of as list of lists. Each list contains the indices of the atoms in a molecule to be averaged over.

```
def centroids_by_mol(xyz: np.ndarray, mol_atom_indices: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    @param xyz: N x 3 numpy array
    
    Return centroids of all molecules 
    """
    mol_count = len(mol_atom_indices)
    coms = np.empty((mol_count, 3))
    for mi in range(mol_count):
        coms[mi] = np.mean(xyz[mol_atom_indices[mi]], axis=0)
    return coms
```

For example, here I pretend there are 2 molecules with 4 atoms, and we are interested in averaging the 1st two atom's coordinates for each molecule

```
In [6]: xyz = np.arange(24); xyz.shape = 8,-1

In [7]: xyz
Out[7]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]])

In [8]: centroids_by_mol(xyz, [[0, 1], [4,5]])
Out[8]:
array([[ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5],
       [13.5, 14.5, 15.5]])
```

Comment: `xyz[[[0,1],[4,5]],:].mean(1)`, IIUC.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. If you make it into an answer, I will accept it